# Change this to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("class1")[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("class2")[0];
b.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'});
```

**Please change this code to jquery .**

**and please tell me how can i change `behavior :'smooth'` to second . forExample (2sec)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert by

`document.getElementsByClassName("class1")` change to `$(".class1")`

```js
var a = $(".class1").click(function () {
   var b = $(".class2");
   b[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class1">

class1
</div>

<div class="class2">
class2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert `document.getElementsByClassName("class1")` to `$(".class1")`

`scrollIntoView` to [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
$('.class1').click(function() {
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
      scrollTop: $('.class2').offset().top,
    },
    2000, // m sec
  );
});
```